# Mysql regex to retrieve string with more then 6 digits in between of any string type (aphabets or non-alphabets)

Tags: mysql, regex

I am required to retrieve only those data rows that match certain pattern, like:

```
asdasdasd123456@gmail.com

genuineemail90867889@yahoo.com
```

Need to retrieve, strings with pattern `{all_string}{digits_morethen_6}{all_strings}` in MYSQL, can anyone help me with the right regex to implement in the sql script

Comment: I understand the down vote, but I have done much research on google can couldn't find any regex expression to work with my issue, so did post on SO. As me being a total know-nothing in regex patterns any help is appreciated though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE col REGEXP '[0-9]{7}'
```

That looks for 7 digits (more than 6) anywhere in a string.

If you need the parts before and after to be non-empty, then:

```
WHERE col REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{7,}[^0-9]'
```

This looks for at least 7 digits, preceded and followed by a non-digit.

**Edit**

Examples (of second REGEXP):

```
mysql> SELECT 'asdf2345zxcv' REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{7,}[^0-9]';
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 'asdf2345zxcv' REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{7,}[^0-9]' |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                             0 |
+-----------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT 'asdf2344444445zxcv' REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{7,}[^0-9]';
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 'asdf2344444445zxcv' REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{7,}[^0-9]' |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   1 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: it returned 0 rows, may be the regex is only looking for strings with only numbers, i see "^" there but

Comment: Its actually works when used alone without any other where conditions,

Comment: `^` at the start "anchors" to the beginning; I did not need that. `^`, at the start of a set of characters `[^0-9]` inverts the set; "not digits" in this case

Comment: Do you have a SELECT for which my `REGEXP` fails?

Comment: this works great -=>`select * from someTable where (email REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{5,}[^0-9]');` But this doesn't  => `select * from someTable where id = 1 and email REGEXP '[^0-9][0-9]{5,}[^0-9]'; `

Comment: What is the email for id=1?

Comment: email is the String and the id is int, for example id = 1 and email = "genuineemailnot123123123@gmail.com"

Comment: thanks for the answer @rick-james, solved the issue with the id as well.